# How to send a pandas dataframe as a file via telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I need to send a dataframe to user in my Telegram Bot. The table is not large, but still it doesn't fit in the screen if I format it as HTML with the help of `PrettyTable` library.

Is there a way to send the dataframe as a file? Did not find an existing solution :(

Comment: Sure, via `send_document` - you'll just have to build a document from the dataframe first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
my_bytes = pickle.dumps(df, protocol=4)
file_obj = io.BytesIO(my_bytes)
file_obj.name = "test_file.xlsx"
bot.send_document(chat_id, file_obj)
```